# Кавычки при упоминании слов

Tags: пунктуация, частицы

*Слова это, это когда, это есть употребляются в определениях.*

Есть ли необходимость заключать в кавычки слова "это", "это когда", "это есть" в данном предложении? Могут ли они иметь общие кавычки?

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки нужны. В таких случаях мы имеем слово (понятие) и пример этого слова (понятия), который нужно взять в кавычки. Общие кавычки можно, только если эти слова встречаются в тексте именно в таком порядке подряд (как цитата из текста). А если порядок можно поменять, то в кавычки следует брать каждый пример.

Answer (score 1):

Да, кавычки нужны и они не могут быть общими. Можно не кавычки, а дополнительное выделение: курсив на фоне обычного шрифта или полужирный дополнительно на ваш курсив. В этом случае выделение правильнее сделать общим.

Словом, предлагаю такие варианты:

> Слова "это", "это когда", "это есть" употребляются в определениях.
>   *Слова **это, это когда, это есть** употребляются в определениях.*

В случае их полужирного выделения рассчитываю, что читатель поймёт, что надо читать так, как подразумевается в первом примере. Если важно подчеркнуть, что слова рассматриваются по отдельности, или не допустить иного восприятия, взял бы всё же каждое в кавычки. Иногда я сочетаю курсив и кавычки для красоты.

Comment: А как отличить общее от индивидуального? По вертикальным запятым?

Comment: @shampar: не совсем понимаю. К примерам я предлагаю применить более сильное выделение.

Comment: В свою очередь не понимаю к каким примерам? Есть — одна — фраза, в которой предлагается выделить перечисленные слова, и выделить их можно порознь шестью кавычками или целиком — двумя. Последнее будет общим выделением этих слов. Вы говорите, это не тот способ который подходит, а нужно общее выделение полужирным или курсивом. Хорошо, пусть так. Спрашиваю: чем общее будет отличаться от частного? Наклонными пробелами и наклонными запятыми? Вы бы показали в ответе, как это выглядит — выделение правильнее сделать общим.

Comment: @shampar: чем общее от частного? Я имею в виду, что оставил бы запятые и не стал бы на них прерывать выделение (делать их обычными). А вот что такое "наклонные пробелы" и "вертикальные/наклонные запятые" совсем не понимаю... *выделить их можно порознь шестью кавычками или целиком — двумя* — да, я предлагаю порознь шестью.

Comment: Вы бы показали в ответе, как это выглядит — выделение правильнее сделать общим.

Comment: @shampar: спасибо за совет, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @shampar А разве пробелы могут быть наклонными? Пробел - это же отсутствие символа, пустота.

Comment: @shampar: дошло про вертикальные/наклонные запятые и пробелы. Я бы делал наклонные в расчёте, что все поймут, что слова рассматриваются в отдельности. Делал бы так ради эстетики и в соответствии с тем, как бывает в словарях. Пробелы, конечно, выглядят одинаково вроде, но формально бы тоже наклонными делал. Но если важно подчеркнуть, что слова рассматриваются по отдельности, взял бы всё же каждое в кавычки. Иногда я сочетаю курсив и кавычки для красоты.